# Change cursor aligment vertically in multi-line JTextField

Tags: java, swing, jtextfield, cursor-position, jtextcomponent

I have the following JTextField where I would like to change the cursor position from the middle to the TOP of the JTextField:

[image]

How do I accomplish that?

Comment: Did you go through http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1351959/jtextfield-default-cursor-position

Comment: I did, and that answers the horizontal aligment, not vertical.

Comment: JTextField only accepts single-line input, making it so tall would confuse the user - is there a good reason for this?

Comment: The JTextField isn't actually for input, but rather output for some text in a "nice" box. I've switched the JTextField to a JTextArea and that seems to solve my problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no such thing as a multi-line `JTextField`. What you posted is a regular, single-line `JTextField` which is simply stretched out.

If you need mutli-line text components, consider using a `JTextArea` or `JTextPane` in which you can perfectly set the cursor (caret) at the first line

*Edit*

Just read your comment. An editable textfield for output is just confusing to the user. At least make it non-editable, or opt for a `JLabel` with a `Border`